# Issue sorting in PHP 2 items per row

Tags: php, sorting, rows, break

I built a code in which some items are loaded from a db and shown in rows 2 by 2. Basically, when the counter is an even number, it adds a line break and goes to the next row.

My issue is that now only the first 2 rows are fine. The third row has only 1 item and placed to the right and then there is a line break. Then row 4 is also ok showing 2 items.

Here is the graph:

```
ITEM1  ITEM2  
ITEM3  ITEM4  
       ITEM5
ITEM6  ITEM7
```

Here is my code:

```
while($info = $items->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
echo "<div name='item' id='".$info['color_base1']."' class='itemBox'><div class='showItem'><a href='items_descr.php?itemId=".$info[id_item]."'><img class='itemImage' alt='' src='images/$info[imageMid].jpg'></img></div><br />";
echo "<div class='indexItemText'><font class='similarItemsText'><a href='items_descr.php?itemId=".$info[id_item]."'>".$info[name]."</a><font class='price'> - $".$info[price]."</div></div>";
$row_count++;
if ($row_count % 2 == 0) 
    {
echo "<br />"; // close the row if we're on an even record
    }

}
```

Comment: did you check the generated html? is it what you expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this first, to be sure you're getting the data you expect.

```
while($info = $items->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
    var_dump($info);
}
```

If that looks right, add in the logic to count the rows 2x2.  And if that looks right, then begin to add in the HTML that wraps the data.  By doing it stepwise, and in that order, it will be easier to get it correct.

Comment: Hi, I checked and I am getting the items I expect to see. The only issue is the display in the 3rd row....